# Codeeffects - Cannot load rule on UI that has In Rule Method with more than 255 string parameter value

Tags: codeeffects

It seems that CodeEffect library 4.3.2.6 has an issue with rule XML editing ON UI and  transformation back from stroage to  show it on UI for editing when rule XML has **In Rule method** call with **string** parameter that has string value passed in **longer than 255 characters**.

Is it made intentionally to avoid long rules to be edited on UI or just a bug so someone knows workaround for it?
To avoid any side effects from my code I downloaded and  used **Business Rule** code example from codeeffects site [Code Effects Demo Projects](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Demo-Project) and opened it in VS2015.

In "Patient.cs" file added following code to

```
public class Patient 
{
...
// In Rule Method that accepts only one string parameter
[Method("[NumberOfSegments]")]
public int RuleMethod01(
            // explicitly specify maximum string allowed
            [Parameter(ValueInputType.User,Max = 10000)] 
            string val)
        {
            return val.Split(',').Length;
        }

}
```

On UI(using Ajax controller)  I attempted to create rule with long string parameter passed in (in real project I need such long string since it contains unique parameters for In Rule method to use for calculations and cannot rely on the data sources approach that CodeEffects can offer)

```
Check if [NumberOfSegments] ("1111,2222,33333,4444,55555,6666,777,8888,999,0000,1111,222,333,44444,1231231,123123123,123123123,123123123,123123123,123123123,123123123,123123123,123123123,123132123,123123123,123123123,123123123,123123123,12123123,123123123,123123123,123123123,1231231233") greater than 12
```

But even that I explicitly specified maximum string length for parameter as **10000** in attribute **Parameter** UI does not allow me to enter string that has length more than **256** characters. 
Documentation on CodeEffects site 
[Business-Rules-Data-Types](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rules-Data-Types) does not mentioned any built-in restrictions and only way to restrict length of the string parameter use  Parameter Attribute and its **Max** property.

Did  anyone ran into the issue with such "synthetic" restrictions and can point me to the documentation or any workaround for that?
Thank you in advance for the any meaningful suggestions

PS: Just small update - when I manually edited Rule XML file and provided longer string as parameter (e.g. around 500 characters) I could not load it from the XML back to the UI the RuleEditor::Rule::InvalidElements collection contained one element with **Hint** property value **"v122"** dont know if its helpful but may be CodeEffects authors can know more about such Hint and what v122 means.

Answer (score 0):

Strings longer than 255 chars (neither property values nor method params) are not supported in Code Effects. v122 is the error number that you get in response. Its original message is "The length of the value of this string element exceeds the maximum allowed limit".

Comment: Why such restriction added? Documentation states that maximum length of string parameter is only limited by the ParameterAttribute::Max property. So please specify that explicitly. BTW: When rule XML has been modified in text editor to accept more than 255 characters it successfully evaluated on server side layer so seems this restriction is only for UI editor ?

Comment: Documentation for ParameterAttribute states [link](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Parameter-Attribute)  that 
**Max Type: System.Int64**  _For string parameters, gets or sets the maximum length of the string that rule authors can type as the value._